# Do not update records in the database Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I can not understand why, but the records in the database are not updated ... All data reaches, even after the save () method if you dump the object, then the data from the form is stored correctly, and in the database itself there is no change, besides it is not the first method updating the data, making stores with the same method and everything worked, even in this project the category editing method works. Here's the actual method:

```
public function UpdateCountry(Request $request)
{
    $Countries = Countries::where('Id', $request->get('Id'))->first();
    $Countries->Country   = $request->get('Country');
    $Countries->Continent = $request->get('Continent');
    $Countries->Class     = $request->get('Class');
    $Countries->save();

    return back()->with('status', 'Updated success!');
}
```

Model fillable:

```
protected $fillable = ['Id', 'Country', 'Class', 'Continent'];
```

Routes, which use this method:

```
Route::get('country/editor/edit/{Id}','AdminController@EditCountry')->name('EditCountry');
Route::post('country/editor/save','AdminController@UpdateCountry')->name('UpdateCountry');
```

A similar method for editing categories that works.

```
public function UpdateCat(Request $request) {
    $data               = $request->all();
    $Category           = Categories::find($data['id']);
    $Category->Category = $data['Category'];
    $Category->save();

    return back()->with('status', 'Updated success');
}
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>
                @if (session('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        {{ session('status') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
 <div class="container">
                    <form action="{{route('UpdateCountry')}}" method="post">
                        @foreach($Country as $item)
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Country">Country</label>
                            <input type="hidden" value="{!! $item->Id !!}" name="Id" id="Id">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" name="Country"  value="{{$item->Country}}" required>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Continent">Continent</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Continent" name="Continent" value="{{$item->Continent}}" required>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                            <input type="hidden" id="Class" name="Class" value="flag flag-default">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                    </form>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Any error messages, logs ... ?

Comment: No. All is successfully executed. And on the dump of the object after the storage, new data hangs.

Comment: Edit your question, code in comments is hard to read, most do not bother.

Comment: Look, I changed

Comment: Do you have the $fillable property set correctly? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment. Without seeing the rest of your code it's really hard to say what the issue is.

Comment: This is the case, that everything is correctly installed, and one update method works, and in the past projects there were no problems with it.

Comment: In that case show the rest of your code and the code that calls it.

Comment: Do you have any unique constraints in the database? The code above looks OK. You'll need to provide more.

Comment: Look, I changed

Comment: I break my head and can not understand what the problem is))
It's really getting funny, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this question, and it turned out to be very simple. In the model it was necessary simply to indicate:

```
protected $primaryKey = ['Id'];
```